# Using `await` on Protractor `element().getAttribute()` gives error: "Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise..."

Tags: typescript, async-await, protractor

I'm writing behavioral tests for an Angular2 app using Protractor, and I'm new to async/await syntax. This problem has brought me to a halt. Can someone explain why I get the Typescript error `Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.` in the `isLogoFooterPresent()` method, and how to fix it?

I have the following simple Protractor spec that tries to verify that an image is displayed by checking the image's width.

Here's an excerpt from my e2e-spec.ts file:

```
import { LoginPage, Layout } from '../page_objects';

describe('Login page', () => {
  it('Should have the logo in the footer', async () => {
    await LoginPage.navigateTo();
    await expect(Layout.isFooterLogoPresent).toBe(true);
  })
});
```

And here's a snippet from the my Layout page object that has visibility to the logo image in question. The line with the `await element(...).getAttribute(...)` chain that causes the error.

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor/globals';

export class Layout {
  static get isFooterLogoPresent() {
    return ( async () => { // <-- this wrapping is necessary to use async/await in getter method
      return await element(by.css('.content-footer img')).getAttribute('naturalWidth') > 0; // <-- PROBLEM HERE
    })
  }
}
```

The following promise-based syntax (which works) is what I'm trying to replace:

```
  static get isFooterLogoPresent() {
    return element(by.css('.content-footer img')).getAttribute('naturalWidth') // naturalWidth attr is 0 if image is missing
      .then( imgWidth => imgWidth > 0 );
  }
```

BTW, I am using Typscript 2.3.2 and Protractor 5.2.0.
I appreciate any wisdom you've got. Thanks!

Comment: Smells like a problem with the Protractor type definition files. What are you using for that?

Comment: Make sure that you are long longer using the former control flow: https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait

Comment: Ah @MadaraUchiha, I don't have any specific typescript accommodations for protractor. Do I need `@types/protractor` in my package.json devDependencies, or something else? (Such a package exists, but it hasn't been updated for a year and doesn't have the download velocity to suggest that it's the common solution.) And thanks Florent B; yes, I do have the protractor control flow turned off in my protractor config.

Comment: Aren't you actually trying to return `true/false`? If so, why not wrapping your check in an `expect`-statement? something like `return await expect(element(by.css('.content-footer img')).getAttribute('naturalWidth')).not.toBe(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming to the conclusion that Protractor 5.2 is not ready for async/await syntax yet. If anybody gets it working robustly, I'd love to know how and what version. At the moment, if you dig down to the `getAttribute()` source, it returns a `ElementFinder` object, not a Promise. This object has a `.then()` method on it, so you can *use* the result like a promise by chaining the `.then()`, but TypeScript (rightfully) won't recognize it as a proper promise, which is what `await` expects.

For the moment, I am giving up on async/await for this Protractor project. I am falling back to handling asynchronous behavior entirely with promises instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add parentheses for your await -

```
  import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor/globals';

  export class Layout {
    static get isFooterLogoPresent() {
      return ( async () => {
        return (await $('.content-footer img').getAttribute('naturalWidth')) > 0;
      })
    }
  }
```

This will apply `> 0` to resolved value, not to comparison expression

BUT! You have error over here:

```
await expect(Layout.isFooterLogoPresent).toBe(true);
```

function `isFooterLogoPresent` is still returns a promise, so you asserting promise object to be true, it will be always true according to how object comparison in JS works.
Change to this to fix false positive test:

```
await expect(await Layout.isFooterLogoPresent).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. Explicitly scoping the await operator with parenthesis did not change the error I get. To your second point about await-ing the parameter to `expect()`, the Protractor/Jasmine syntax expects a promise, so you don't have to explicitly await the parameter until it resolves. (I appreciate the attempt to help!)

Comment: @MatthewMarichiba
Error is different - now it is saying that cannot apply > operator to a string. Add parseInt
return parseInt(await element(by.css('.content-footer img')).getAttribute('naturalWidth')) > 0;